# The decision procedure of theory of closed real field is in NP-hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, complexity-classes, computational-geometry

The decision procedure of theory of closed real field  refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, even in the purely existential case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals

Comment: ... and this holds for any first-order theory that admits some model with at least two elements, not just for the real field.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't quite right. If a consistent theory T *proves* the existence of at least two elements, the existential theory of T is NP-hard. If a theory T is only *consistent* with the existence of at least two elements, then satisfiability of existential sentences in a model of T is NP-hard, or in other words, the universal theory of T is coNP-hard.